# Prevent indent in exam class so that I can repeat question text on next page (next part)

Tags: exam

How can I make a repeated question not indent using documentclass `exam`?

I want to repeat the question number and text on the next page, for part B. I've tried just retyping the question, including question number that I know it's going to get and the `\noindent` (as you can see below), but no help.

```
\begin{questions}

\question Question 1

\newpage
\question QUESTION 2 TEXT

\begin{parts}
\part Question 2, Part A

\newpage
\noindent 2. Repeat QUESTION 2 TEXT

\part Question 2, part B

\end{parts}
\end{questions}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `exam` class has two commands for this:

`\uplevel{}` moves up one level, so it writes its argument at the "question" level from within a "parts" list.  It does include the normal paragraph indentation.

`\fullwidth{}` writes its argument without any indentation as if it were outside the `questions` environment.

You probably want the `\uplevel{}` command.

Documentation: Section 6. http://www-math.mit.edu/~psh/exam/examdoc.pdf

Comment: Yup. Worked well enough. It doesn't have the overhang, but I can live without that.